# Error al ejecutar tarea Celery task con Django debug=False

Tags: django, redis, celery

se trata de un task de Celery para envío de correo electrónico, lo curioso que funciona todo correctamente en modo `DEBUG=True`, pero no funciona en producción `DEBUG=False`. Ejecutando `celery worker -A facturo2 --loglevel=debug` durante la acción del envío y en modo debug activado muestra lo siguiente:

```
 ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-5] Task enviar_documentos[987a12a6-7f93-4d0a-b130-031b67fc8a8e] raised unexpected: TypeError("enviar_documentos_async() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cliente'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/apps/fotocopiadoras.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 385, in trace_task
R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/apps/fotocopiadoras.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 648, in __protected_call__
return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: enviar_documentos_async() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cliente'[2019-04-27 00:53:47,142: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task enviar_documentos[90c39f62-bead-4d2d-8315-e200bcb113dc] raised unexpected: 
TypeError("enviar_documentos_async() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cliente'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/apps/fotocopiadoras.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 385, in trace_task
R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/apps/fotocopiadoras.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 648, in __protected_call__
return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
```

TypeError: enviar_documentos_async() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cliente'

Primero el fichero que inicia el envío con el delay:

```
from django.conf import settings
from notificaciones.tasks import enviar_documentos_async

def enviar_documentos(empresa, cliente, documentos, tipo,template="factura", context=None):
    enviar_documentos = enviar_documentos_async.delay
    enviar_documentos(tipo=tipo,
                      empresa=empresa.pk,
                      cliente=cliente.pk,
                      template=template,
                      context=context)
```

Segundo, el task:

```
  from celery_app import app

  @app.task(name="enviar_documentos")
  def enviar_documentos_async(empresa, cliente, documentos, tipo="FacturaVenta", template="factura", context=None):
       if not context:
          context = {}
       klass = KLASS.get(tipo)
       queryset = klass.objects.filter(pk__in=documentos)
       em = Empresa.objects.get(pk=empresa)
       cl = Cliente.objects.get(pk=cliente)

       ....
       return enviar_email(
                      mail_from="\"{0.nombre}\" <{0.email}>".format(em),
                      mail_to=cl.email,
                      tipo=template,
                      context=context,
                      adjuntos=adjuntos)
```

Tercero, el envío del email:

```
  from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
  from django.template import Context, Template

  def enviar_email(mail_from, mail_to, tipo, context=None, adjuntos=None):
      subject = Template(tipo.asunto).render(mail_context).replace("\n", " ")
      message = Template(tipo.cuerpo).render(mail_context)
      ...
      msg = EmailMessage(
                subject,
                linebreaks(message),
                mail_from,
                mail_to)
```

Versiones apps instaladas mediante pip en el virtualenv:

```
     celery               4.3.0
     Django               2.1.1   
     django-extensions    2.0.7   
     django-filter        2.1.0    
     django-oauth-toolkit 1.1.3       
     django-redis         4.10.0  
     django-redis-cache   2.0.0   
     djangorestframework  3.8.2 
     redis                3.2.1   
     redis-cache          0.1.5   
     redis-structures     0.1.7  
     kombu                4.5.0
```

En el servidor Linux-4.9.0-3-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-9.0 + nginx + uwsgi:

```
 Redis server v=5.0.4 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.1.0 bits=64
 Celery 4.3.0 (rhubarb)
```

Una parte de Settings.py

```
...
DJANGO_ROOT = dirname(abspath(__file__))
SITE_HTDOCS = normpath(join(DJANGO_ROOT, '../htdocs'))
STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(SITE_HTDOCS, 'static'))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = normpath(join(SITE_HTDOCS, 'media'))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
...
# CELERY
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

Answer (score 0):

con Django en producción `debug=False`, Celery no funciona directamente ejecutando: `celery worker -A myapp --loglevel=debug`, es necesario además inicar los scripts de Celery [demonización](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#usage-systemd)